# Reduce Unity Editor loading times

Tags: unity, performance, loading

- Open project => Wait
- Start / stop game => Wait
- Change script => Wait
- Move object from project view => Wait
- You blink too often => WAIT even more !

And so on and so on....
And the bigger the project gets the more you have to wait.

I feel like I am going insane with all this waiting. I am seriously loosing my sanity here when even the slightest thing requires a million of years loading time.

What I have done so far to mitigate all this:

- Use Hot reload for partially reducing script reloads
- Enabled manual project refresh instead of automatic one from visual
  studio
- Enable "enter play mode" and disabled "reload domain" and "reload
  scene"
- Disabled autosave/refresh for light baking
- Disabled prefab auto save

What I want to find out:

- Is there a way to boost allocated memory to Unity ? It isnt an
  elegant solution but it will be a good start.
- How to disable the automatic Unity reload every time I move a script
  inside the Project window ?
- Any other way to speed up this cursed program before I loose my
  sanity completely

PC Specs:
CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820X CPU @ 3.60GHz
Ram : 32.0 GB
V_Card : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
Storage: SSD with NVME

Unity ver: Unity 2021.1.

Reload times:

- "Reloading script assemblies" + 15 sec
- "Compiling C# scripts" milliseconds.

Comment: Have you reviewed [previous answers to how to speed up reloads in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/153401/39518) and [the Unity documentation on separating your code into smaller assemblies that can be recompiled independently](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)?

Comment: I'd also be interested in what is leading you to believe that this is a RAM limitation.

Comment: I've noticed that if I use the Unity Editor for many hours without closing it, the reloading gets slower and slower. This could be a memory leak or something to do with the log file getting very large. Either way, closing and re-opening the Editor fixes the issue. Are you using an HDD or SSD? What version of Unity are you using? What are your PC specs?

Comment: Hmm maybe I am talking nonsense so please correct me here. Currently in my project "Reloading script assemblies" takes the longest to load. And "Compiling C# scripts" is few milliseconds. And if I spend time doing the assembly definitions thing, all its going to do is speed up the "Compiling C# scripts" which is already pretty fast. 

As to the RAM thing its my mistake. I just meant if I can allocate more CPU or GPU or Ram or whatever else is there. So I can make Unity load faster.

Comment: @kevin  
Restarting the editor doesn't improve things. 
Specs =>
CPU : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820X CPU @ 3.60GHz
Ram : 32.0 GB
V_Card : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
hard drive : SSD
Unity ver :2021.1

I am also using allot of Unity plugins. I suspect the loading times is because of them, though I am not sure how can I improve the situation.

Comment: @theCodeHermit Unity 2021.1 is old. The first thing you should try is updating to the latest version of Unity 2021.3, in case your performance issues are caused by a bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: Ahhhh. The plugins are a likely culprit. A lot of plugins will subscribe to events that fire anytime *any* file is updated then call slow search functions to find all files they care about, just in case one of the files they touch was the one that was edited. Can you make a new project and import the plugins you're using one at a time, timing the reload after each, to try to narrow down which one(s) might be the biggest contributors to loading times? Also: please edit your question to include the points about your hardware specs, time in reload script assemblies vs compiling c# scripts, etc.

Comment: @DMGregory Ah I didnt think of that, but it does make allot of sense. I was thinking of doing the 1 by 1 test of them, but I dont have time for it at the moment. Will do it at some point. I already have a few ideas which ones are the culprits, but even if I know for sure that they are causing it I wouldn't be able to do much about it I guess. And I cant remove them since I use them everywhere in the project.

Comment: If you have access to their source code you might be able to find their event subscription and replace it with a manual refresh, but that's a lot of work digging in third-party code, and some plugins just offer a pre-compiled DLL where that gets even harder.

Comment: That's just how it is. Unity Editor is a slow behemoth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally after more than a year I found what was messing with my load times !!

I have "Easy Save 3" plugin from the Unity store. The manager object in the scene was glitching out. I deleted it and everything is lightning fast now. You must delete it and not disable. Disable does nothing and I was fooled by that when checking my components for problems before.

It was giving me problems even before, but never that much. I figured it was Unity not being optimized since the slowdown happened gradually and I have seen lots of similar topics blaming Unity.

Hopefully this will help anyone else who has similar problems.